# Flutter Firebase Auth emulator restart causes iOS simulator to go in a loop

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, ios-simulator, firebase-tools

I am building an iOS and using Firebase auth emulator for local dev environment. Due to an auto-update restart, the emulator was closed. Since I had no interest in persistence, I did not back it up. Trying to run the app in the simulator right now throws the app in a loop.

The device state is logged in, while the user does not exist on the emulator backend. I tried deleting the app in the Simulator device, but that does not change anything.

I have been Yak shaving for the past 3 days. Is there a solution?